# How to use regex to match multiplications

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regex to match the multiplication function after the colon:

```
  Product in Inches (L x W x H):    19.75 x 19.0 x 33.75
```

I have tried these expressions so far:

```
  Product in Inches \(L \* W \* H\):\s*([\d.\*]*)
  Product in Inches \(L \* W \* H\):\s*([\d.]*.*)
```

But these don't work. May I know how I should represent the multiplication sign and the function? What did I do wrong?

P.S., I am not writing Regex in any programming language. I am just writing Regex in a web scraping tool.

Thank you!

Comment: Do these multiplications always appear after colon and nothing appears after that till end of line? That can solve your problem in much easier way then. Besides your x is literally x character and not multiplication sign

Comment: Hey, thank you! Just figured out the answer. yes the multiplication sign should not be represented by asterisk.

Comment: You didnt figure it out, but nvm you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Product in Inches \(L x W x H\):\s*(\d+.?\d*) x (\d+.?\d*) x (\d+.?\d*)
```

I used this site to figure it out:
https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thank you! Yours is actually better than my solution. One correction though - there is a larger parenthesis you forgot; it should be: Product in Inches \(L x W x H\):\s*((\d+.?\d*) x (\d+.?\d*) x (\d+.?\d*)).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, never mind. Just figured out an answer:

```
 Product in Inches \(L x W x H\):\s*([\d.]*.*)
```

This would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
:\s*(\S+)\s*x\s*(\S+)\s*x\s*(\S+)
```

And in case you have just a single space between operands you can use:

```
:\s*(\S+) x (\S+) x (\S+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZ9dD2/1)**